# Can I use MailMerge and MS Words as Report Generator instead of Access Report?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

> This is not about coding question. It's about Software (Database) Design.

Background: My office has a ADP database as front and SQL Server is a backend. There are a dozen of basic standard reports in the ADP file. End users slightly change reports every year such as adding some texts, changing logo, bolds, highlights. I help them back and forth for updating these. After they are ok with the report, I upload to the server so other users can use it. I do this over and over over the time (hundreds times). I think there should be a better way.

Recently, I test a new design by splitting Report and Database. I let user create a words file for the report that they like. I add MailMerge fields in the report after they're done. My users are very good in MS Words. In the database, I add standard MailMerge code. When users pick what template (docx) they want for a report then runs it, it works fine.

Question: Can I use MailMerge and MS Words as Report Generator instead of Access Report? if it's work fine, I will rollout to all the reports. I just want to miss anything before doing so.

```
Pro(s)
- Users can add any complex format to a report (almost anything you can imagine in MS Words, which you can't do in Access)
- I have less work. No recode, recomplie, or reupload.

Con(s)
- Report Desinger is run faster than MailMerge for a large report.  
- Train user how to update MailMerge fields
```

Comment: I suggest you create code to output CSV, rather than link directly to Access. You can find some useful notes here: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5088

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Word and MailMerge to create reports. However, keep in mind that you're giving up control, since users could edit the templates in a way that breaks your MailMerge.